# How do you choose the right Ruby gem for your next project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

Suppose you spent the last six months on a legacy system project, large corp obsolete web platform, integrating alien data structures.

Now you are finally off and you can go with a brand new startup project in Ruby.

The application will be built from scratch and is up to you to decide which gem you are going to use.

The question can be extended to the various aspects of building a brand new web application, but for semplicity, just suppose you need an authentication system.

Now, the last time you put in place that in Rails, was "authlogic" and it was so cool compared whith "authentication_fu", but while you where "in the cave" you just heard about several other way to authenticate, something like clearance, device, omniauth, warden, sorcery,  twitter-auth, open_id_authentication and may others.

Even worst, suppose you can "just imagine" Ruby community is not sleeping and in six months, she was blowing up new ideas and paradigms about "authentication pattern" but you didn't find the time to be updated.

You just want to go outside there, having a look at what's going on, finding all the new gem arising and deciding what fill better your next project.

How do you do it ?

Thanks in advance
Luca G. Soave

```
UPDATE Sep 18 10:36
```

[Ruby toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) compares gems in the same category by the metrics described - by Andrew Grimm

```
UPDATE Sep 17 02:09
```

Several people tried to clarify the process to discover and choose the right Ruby gem for "the next brand new Ruby project". I'd like to summarize what I learned from everyone by listing what in my comprension are the main steps :

About the process of deciding between gems in the same field:

1. try a few of them yourself - by semperos
2. give them each a test drive, make sure there is heavy activity on github, watching last
   commits - by ealdent
3. choose the the Loosely Coupled Gems vs Monolitic Frameworks, giving priority to agile and fast implementation and continuous refactoring - by Craig Stuntz
4. getting expert of a gem/domain field, in order to be able to decide between gems - by james_schorr
5. don’t choose “WOW-things and Cool Fresh releases” for your production client projects, but test it daily on minor and private testing projets - by mikhailov

About the process to discover & choose the right gem, the last one by jeremiahd, is a deep, clear and very useful description of the process :

- search around for what seem like the most commonly installed libraries that cover my use case
- take a look at their documentation, to see how complete and readable it seems
- look at the activity in their community : updates - mailing lists - wiki -
  IRC - commits - mood
- look at their code : test suites - clean code - documents - useful comments -
- use their code
- quality of the community and code
- do it as a learning process, get a better programmer and give back to your community

  `END UPDATE Sep 17 02:09`

Feel free to add more, ... share your point of view.

Comment: Ruby toolbox compares gems in the same category by the metrics described.

Comment: ... even if doesn't seem to be updated. Have a look at rails_authentication category for example (http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html) it miss omniauth, warden and many others top gems. Also the IA (information architecture) in terms of "categorization" and "taxonomy" should be improved.

Comment: I think they're planning on fixing it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do (when this problem rears it's head in any language) is I search around for what seem like the most commonly installed libraries that cover my use case. I then take a look at their documentation, to see how complete and readable it seems.

Next I **look at the activity in their community** -- are projects actively updated? Are there easily accessible mailing lists / a wiki/ IRC? How active are they? What's the general tone?

Next I **look at their code**. Are there test suites? Are they test suites that help me understand the library? Is the code clean? Documented? Commented usefully? Does it look like a ridiculous mess, or like it's had thought put into it at every point?

Next I **use their code** in a simplified, but similar, manner to how I actually need to use it. Did I run into any major stumbling blocks?

Screw flipping a coin and sticking with it. Sooner or later, whatever lib you're using isn't going to serve your needs, and you'll want to modify it's behavior. When that time comes, **the quality of the community** and **the quality of the code** are what make libraries stand out from one another.

This is, of course, a bit fuzzy. And it can be a challenging thing to do, but you'll be a better programmer for it, and assuming you do it enough, you'll probably be contributing back upstream to the libraries you use at some point, which is pretty awesome.

Comment: Yes, this a very deep, clear and very useful description of the process. This is the kind of answer I was expecting thanks. Let me wait a bit more before I decide to flag ...

Answer (score 3):

Pick one and run with it. The important point is not what you choose *right now,* but how hard it will be to change your mind six months down the road. In short, your efforts should not go into making one, permanent decision which will bind you for the lifetime of the project, but on isolating the dependencies on the authorization system to a single (as much as possible) small and easily swapped bit of code.

Comment: Yeah, sound good to me too. Agile fast deploy and than refactoring right ? Trying to be slightly decoupled vs monolitic, like in padrino framework vs old rails 2.x Ok now with rails 3.1 has never ever been simple, but when you just run "gem install rails" now days you're installing 30 gems by default. How are you going to to find & choose the next one ? what process are you going to follow ? Googling - Gitwatching - Reading leading Ruby articles and reviews ? What's your discovery process ?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should **try a few of them yourself**.

It seems that [Devise](http://rubygems.org/gems/devise) has become somewhat of a de facto choice, with mechanisms to support a variety of authentication styles. That might be a nice place to *start*, but you should obviously try to make it do what you want, and if it doesn't work, try others of the gems you mention.

Rails does not have a "default" authentication mechanism pre-built because authentication tends to be specific to each project. Try several out, see which one fits your needs and programming style best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I personally like Devise too but, just to decouple the question from the specific gem and knowladge domain, what are you going to do if you have to implement a domain specific problem you still don't know well ? How do you look for all the existing gem / library ? Suppose there are 7 promising gems, how do you chose one ? Do you try them one by one ? Do you find the time to dig into every single code ?

Comment: @LucaG.Soave if you don't understand the problem domain well, then you're probably not in a position to make gem/library decisions. But when you do know your requirements more specifically, my answer is YES, DIG INTO EVERY ONE. If you're responsible for what you're building, you're responsible for the parts you use as well. That said, often the level of activity and age of a project can help decide. If you want use/popularity metrics, check out http://ruby-toolbox.com

Answer (score 3):

I mostly agree with Craig Stuntz, you should just pick one and run with it (and build your app so that it can be swapped out, if possible).

I will suggest, however, that doing that means you give them each a test drive.  Perhaps you don't do that in your main project, but really, until you actually use the thing, you will never know just how messed up it is.  And no matter how much love the community is throwing at a gem today, you can be sure there are serious issues with it.

For relatively new gems, you also need to make sure there is heavy activity on github or whatever, so that the gem isn't going to stagnate any time soon.  If I don't see a commit in the past few weeks, it makes me really uneasy about using a gem that isn't already mature.

Comment: "... make sure there is heavy activity on github" and "... If I don't see a commit in the past few weeks ... makes me really uneasy about using a gem". Suppose you have 2 gems: one have 1685 watchers and 499 forks - the other 2039 watchers and 147 forks both are updated 5 days ago, can you make choices without looking into the code ?

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure which conclusion you'd draw from that one.  The huge number of forks could mean people feel compelled to fix something..  Or it could mean they are that much more excited about that gem than people are about the other.  This is why I suggest diving in and giving each a try.  Maybe it'll become apparent then.

Comment: yes I like your "the empirical way"

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time looking at authentication gems and landed on Devise.  It's been great.  All of the above tips are great.

Comment: Thanks for your contribute. What about choosing a Ruby scheduler gem ? How will you choose between delayed_job, resque-scheduler, whenever and clockwork ?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post on this very question - How to pick the right Ruby Gem?

http://www.railstutors.com/blog/how-to-pick-the-right-ruby-gem

The main idea - First check if really need a gem to do what you want; Then some consideration on how to evaluate a Ruby gem. I also happened to use an Authentication as use case so you may find that interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It is my daily choice, what is the way we go tomorrow to satisfy our clients needs. How to be on the edge and keep users happy with stable and reliable system?

First off, we do not accept WOW-things and Cool Fresh releases. We will use new things in 0.5 year, as a tesing period. Yes, we still on Rails 2.3.10. Upgrade to Rails 3 will be next month for us. We have codebase with Core covered by tests, Rspec do great job for us, there is about 94 tests.

But, we try modern gems during daily development and do small projects to see how they work. It's easy and free, take the time only. Railscasts satisfy interest in cool stuff too, it's important to see each of them.

Comment: get a habbit to look at Github activity things you use. It can takes 1 hour per day, but keeps you happy

Comment: do not let enterprisy and legasy stuff slow down your tempo and loose the interest. ALL that fun on Github and Stackoverflow. You can do more and achieve more with these tools

Comment: Great contribute here mikhailov, thanks for answering and sharing your professional advise about "too new - too cool" objects to be used in production client projects. I apprecite your last advise about "legasy stuff" too. Many thanks.